# Apply and sort using dplyr over a list?

Tags: r, list, dplyr, tidyr

Could someone just explain how I'd use something in the apply family to carry this out across a list...

```
list1[[1]][1:31,] %>% arrange(vuln)
```

Essentially all I need to do is select rows 1:31 and then arrange the dataset using vuln. The above achieves this but does it on the first data frame in the list. I was guessing something similar to this:

```
apply(list1,2,function(x)list[x][1:31] %>% arrange(vuln))
```

but the above doesn't seem to work. Also just for comparisons could I see a loop that would schieve the same?

Thanks!

Comment: You did not provide any data so here is my **guess** `lapply(list1, function(i) {d1 <- i[1:31,]; d1 <- d1[order(d1$vuln),]; d1})`

Comment: `lapply(list1, slice, 1:31) %>% lapply(arrange, vuln)` with just pipe and lapply.

Comment: Vlo's answer seems to have done the trick and is very simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the `tidyverse` way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
your_list <- list(head(iris),tail(iris))
your_list %>% modify(
  . %>% slice(1:3) %>% arrange(Sepal.Length))

# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>
# 1          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>    <fctr>
# 1          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
# 2          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
# 3          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
```

And this is how to  make your solution work with minor corrections :

```
lapply(your_list,function(x) x[1:3,] %>% arrange(Sepal.Length))
```

Comment: Thanks...I think the above is pretty similar to Vlo's answer :)

Comment: Same functions are used, but i'm looping over items only once and he loops twice, and I use `purrr` as it plays better with the pipe notation . Sotos's solution wil be faster though.